# Can I use linear regression for predicting time series?

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, forecasting, linear-model

I have the percentage of defaulted clients in porfolio for different periods as target variable and macroeconomic factors as explanatory variables. Can I use simple linear regression? What other steps should I do in comparison with standard linear regression (stationarity check? check that I shouldn't add lags of y or e as explanatory variables?)

Comment: By default no, as it violates at least one of the assumptions of the model, namely iid outcomes. What is the goal?

Comment: @Cagdas-Ozgenc yes

Comment: @user2974951  the goal is to find out how macroeconomic factors influence default rate. Default rate is how many bank's clients defaulted in a period over how many clients are in portfolio

Comment: @user2974951 so what should I do?

Comment: The simplest option would be to difference the time series to render it stationary (https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411diff.htm), after that continue with regular linear regression on the differenced time series. (Your outcome would change, you would be analyzing relative effects)

Comment: @user2974951 thanks!